# How do I efficiently apply a function row-wise to a NumPy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I want to apply a function to each row of a Numpy matrix in an efficient manner. I have found that using `np.apply_along_matrix(function, 1, array)` gives me the desired result. However, this is incredibly slow, especially when using very large matrices.

I know that the more efficient and *correct* way of mapping my function to the matrix rows is to vectorize it, but I don't know how to properly vectorize this function (note that I do not mean `np.vectorize(function)` as this would apply to each element as opposed to each row).

```
import numpy as np


def f(x):
    return x * x.sum() # Multiply each element of a vector by the sum of the vector


a = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)

b = np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, a)
print(b)
# [[  0  10  20  30  40]    Desired output
#  [175 210 245 280 315]]

c = f(a)
print(c)
# [[  0  45  90 135 180]    Incorrect output of trying to apply f to matrix a
#  [225 270 315 360 405]]
```

How would I go about vectorizing this function, and functions like this one to optimize speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *vectorization* to apply the function f to a 2D array.

`a * a.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)`

Here, we sum the elements of the array `a` along the horizontal axis (1), and make it a column vector (keepdims) to multiply each line of `a` by the corresponding element of the sum vector.

Vectorization is pretty efficient. You can learn more about it on [this webpage](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html)